# Android Volley imageloader with % progress while downloading images

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-volley

I am trying to load a lot of images from server using Android Volley library.

I am curious to, is there any way i can find out the % progress of the image being downloaded.

`ImageLoader` contains onError and onSuccess only. If not, is there any better library to provide this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, you made loading an image as download a file, ImageLoader basically perform a single-session request, does not fulfill your purpose. if you still looking for a library that advantage by Volley but offered a file downloader implementation, then you have [Netroid](https://github.com/vince-styling/Netroid).

you can perform a download request for your image, that make you be capable of showing the progress, once download successfully, you perform loading the local file as a Bitmap to display into ImageView. this approach was indirectly but i think it work for you.